# NestedScrollview not working with Drawerlayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawerlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to add nested scroll view in my drawer layout but the nested scroll view is not working i.e. my view is not scrolling down. My content main lahout is supposed to be a scrolling layout. My layout contains a linear layout for toolbar and the content main for the home screen and a navigation view . Any type of help will be grateful. Here's my XML file code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/drawer_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <include
                layout="@layout/content_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">
        
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Not working in terms of what? Can you describe what you expect and what you got

Comment: The view is not scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

set NestedScrollView height to  `match_parent`